# How to access a value in a list within a json string using SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column in a table called "profile" which stores info in the following format(below):

```json
[{"id":"X","type":"location"}],"avatar":{"id":"X","type":"Avatar"},"gender":{"id":"F","type":"Gender","value":"F"},"contacts":[{"id":"0230", "role": "teacher", "school": "XYZ"}],"lastName":"","nickname":"B","religion":{"id":"Unknown","type":"Religion"},"birthDate":"2a","ethnicity":{"id":"NotStated","type":"Ethnicity","category":"OtherEthnicGroups"},"firstName":"","nameTitle":""}
```

How can i access the values for `role` and `school` within `contacts`? I have tried using:
`profile->'contacts'->'role'` and `profile->'contacts'->0->'role'` but both of these don't work as expected.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is the message I get, when casting this content to json: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json

Answer (score 0):

With a valid json you could use the function json_to_recordset():

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM json_to_recordset(profile->'contacts') as j(id int, role text, school text);
```

If your data type is jsonb, you should use the jsonb-function jsonb_to_recordset().